# Spark using Python : save RDD output into text files

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying the word count problem in spark using python. But I am facing the problem when I try to save the output RDD in a text file using .saveAsTextFile command. Here is my code. Please help me. I am stuck. Appreciate for your time.

```
import re

from pyspark import SparkConf , SparkContext

def normalizewords(text):
    return re.compile(r'\W+',re.UNICODE).split(text.lower())

conf=SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("sorted result")
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)

input=sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/PythonTask/sample.txt")

words=input.flatMap(normalizewords)

wordsCount=words.map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)

sortedwordsCount=wordsCount.map(lambda (x,y):(y,x)).sortByKey()

results=sortedwordsCount.collect()

for result in results:
    count=str(result[0])
    word=result[1].encode('ascii','ignore')

    if(word):
        print word +"\t\t"+ count

results.saveAsTextFile("/var/www/myoutput")
```

Comment: what is the problem, can you show the error please?

Comment: Please format properly your question highlighting the code

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cloudera/PythonTask/sorteddata.py", line 24, in <module>
    results.saveAsTextFile("var/www/myoutput")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'saveAsTextFile'

Comment: Try saving `sortedwordsCount` instead

Comment: Thank you all for all your help.

Comment: saving sortedwordsCount atlast helped me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

since you collected `results=sortedwordsCount.collect()` so, its not RDD. It will be normal python list or tuple.

As you know `list` is python object/data structure and `append` is method to add element.

```
>>> x = []
>>> x.append(5)
>>> x
[5]
```

> Similarly  `RDD` is sparks object/data structure and `saveAsTextFile` is method to write the file. Important thing is its distributed data structure.

So, we cannot use `append` on RDD or `saveAsTextFile` on list. `collect` is method on RDD to get to RDD to driver memory.

As mentioned in comments, save `sortedwordsCount` with saveAsTextFile or open file in python and use `results` to write in a file

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. So please tell me how should I proceed now to store the result in a text file. Actually I am new to spark with python programming, so don't know much about this.

Answer (score 1):

Change `results=sortedwordsCount.collect()` to `results=sortedwordsCount`, because using `.collect()` results will be a list.